# Extract items from PrimeFaces Datalist in Java code

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datalist

how can I extract items from Primefaces DataList UIComponent (ie. concatenate their values)? I'm trying to write custom exporter, that's my code:

```
import org.primefaces.component.datalist.DataList;
import org.primefaces.component.export.ExcelExporter;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

public class CustomXLSExporter extends ExcelExporter {

    @Override
    protected String exportValue(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {

        if (component instanceof DataList) {
            DataList dataList = (DataList) component;

            return "values from data-list here";
        } else {
            return super.exportValue(context, component);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you had a look at Primefaces default exporter?

Comment: It does not support embedded collections inside DataTable.